# Docker with Bumblebee on Fedora

Tags: fedora, nvidia, docker, bumblebee, optimus

I have a Notebook (Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro) with a Nvidia MX150. So it's utilizing the Nvidia's Optimus technology. As a distribution, I use Fedora 28.

### Bumblebee

Therefore I installed Bumblebee to take advantage of this technology.

It should be installed correctly since I can start glmark2 via `optirun` or `primusrun`. Also running `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` outputs `ON`.
So the Nvidia GPU should indeed be running.

### Docker

To install docker, I followed the instructions on https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/#install-docker-ce

Running `docker run hello-world` outputs what it should, so docker does also work.

### nvidia-docker2

I got nvidia-docker2 installed on Fedora with this commands:

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/centos7/nvidia-docker.repo | \
  sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-docker.repo
sudo dnf install nvidia-docker2
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
```

### Installed nvidia packages

To check which nvidia packages are installed, I run this command:

`rpm -qa '*nvidia*'`

- Output:akmod-nvidia-396.51-1.fc28.x86_64
- nvidia-container-runtime-2.0.0-1.docker18.06.1.x86_64
- nvidia-driver-396.51-1.fc28.x86_64
- kmod-nvidia-4.17.9-200.fc28.x86_64-396.45-1.fc28.x86_64
- kmod-nvidia-4.17.14-202.fc28.x86_64-396.51-1.fc28.x86_64
- nvidia-docker2-2.0.3-1.docker18.06.1.ce.noarch
- nvidia-driver-libs-396.51-1.fc28.x86_64
- nvidia-container-runtime-hook-1.4.0-1.x86_64
- libnvidia-container1-1.0.0-0.1.rc.2.x86_64
- kmod-nvidia-4.17.12-200.fc28.x86_64-396.45-1.fc28.x86_64
- libnvidia-container-tools-1.0.0-0.1.rc.2.x86_64

### Test docker is running with Nvidia GPU

Unfortunately, docker doesn't currently run with the Nvidia GPU:

`optirun docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

I get this error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:385: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig --device=all --compute --utility --require=cuda>=9.0 --pid=26115 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c00aa7855e42deee545cb07531a571538e0d051d38f45e36584a1c850dd47680/merged]\\\\nnvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.`

### What am I missing?

For now, I am clueless where's the error. I guess it could be a problem with the `CUDA` version.

Answer (score 0):

The only "fix" I've found (more of a work-around) is to ensure the nvidia card is is first loaded / selected via prime-select:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Feels like it's defeating the purpose of using bumblebee